# Is there any inbuilt color picker for windows 8 ( javascript)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, color-picker

I am developing a windows 8 app(Metro) using html5, JavaScript, CSS, etc . I wanted to add a color picker for my app, so that user can change color of background and text.

Is windows 8 provide any inbuilt color picker or should I use external JavaScript color picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in the [developer docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I just [searched](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us/windows/desktop?query=color%20picker&refinement=181&ac=8) for it.

Comment: That's for a Windows Desktop app, not a Metro app.